# master page has runat=server on the head tag element, it is injecting a stylesheet using themes?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

master page has runat=server on the head tag element, it is injecting a stylesheet on the page for some reason and I am not doing it explicitly.

Is it a themes setting that is adding the stylesheet?  How can I disable it for this master page?

Comment: Does the stylesheet go away if you remove runat=server?

Comment: I believe I was getting an error when the head didn't have runat=server, i will check tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I would suspect a theme, to remove it:

- Try `EnableTheming="false"` in your
  masterpage header.
- If you don't want themes at all look 
  for `<pages theme="Name of theme goes here" />` attribute in your
  web.config file and comment it out.